# xml and & issue

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am new to XML and I am now trying to read an xml file.
I googled and try this way to read xml but I get this error.

> Reference to undeclared entity 'Ccaron'. Line 2902, position 9.

When I go to line 2902 I got this,

```
<H0742>&Ccaron;opova 14, POB 1725,
SI-1000 Ljubljana</H0742>
```

This is the way I try

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(file);
            XmlNodeList nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("nodeName");
            foreach (XmlNode n in nodes)
            {
if (n.SelectSingleNode("H0742") != null)
                {
                    row.IrNbr = n.SelectSingleNode("H0742").InnerText;
                }
                .
                .
                .
            }
```

When I look at w3school, ***& is illegal in xml***.

EDIT :
This is the encoding. I wonder it's related with xml somehow.

> encoding='iso-8859-1'

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

They gave me an **.ENT** file and I can reference online ftp.MyPartnerCompany.com/name.ent.
In this .ENT file 
I see entities like that

```
<!ENTITY Cacute "&#262;"> <!-- latin capital letter C with acute,
                                  U+0106 Latin Extended-A -->
```

How can I reference it in my xml Parsing ?
I prefer to reference online since they may add new anytime.
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The XML is invalid, it needs to be modified to remove or escape the & you will struggle to read it as XML until you do.

Comment: Use &#38; or &amp; instead of &

Comment: so you mean using & is a big issue and should never use it ?
My problem is I am getting this XML from other developers I don't know. My other problem is I can't tell them to modify it. What should I do. Thx for the reply !!

Comment: @kevin, you can use `&` in XML documents, you just need to encode it properly.

Comment: Using the '&' symbol directly in XML results in invalid XML (along with '<' and '>' symbols). The content of the node must be encoded such that '&' becomes '&amp;' etc. It's pretty bad of the other developers to expose invalid XML like this. The other option would be to put the entire contents of the node inside a CDATA block...

Comment: How should I put the entire contents under CDATA ? Sorry I am really new to XML.

Comment: The simple answer is that the file you are referring to as an XML file is actually not an XML file, so you cannot read it using XML tools. It could be repaired by adding a reference to a DTD that contains a declaration of the `&Ccaron;` entity.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to be aware of is that the problem isn't in your software.

As you are new to XML, I'm going to guess that definining entities isn't something you've come across before. Character entities are shortcuts for arbitrary pieces of text (one or more characters). The most common place you are going to see them is in the situation you are in now. At some point, your XML has been created by someone who wanted to type the character 'Č' or 'č' (that's upper and lower case C with Caron if your font can't display it).

However, in XML we only have a few predeclared entities (ampersand, less than, greater than, double quote and apostraphe). Any other character entities need to be declared. In order to parse your file correctly you will need to do one of two things - either replace the character entity with something that doesn't cause the parser issues or declare the entity.

To declare the entity, you can use something called an "internal subset" - a specialised form of the DTD statement you might see at the top of your XML file. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE root-element 
   [ <!ENTITY Ccaron "&#x010C;">
     <!ENTITY ccaron "&#x010D;">]
>
```

Placing that statement at the beginning of the XML file (change the 'root-element' to match yours) will allow the parser to resolve the entity.

Alternatively, simply change the `&Ccaron;` to `&#x010C;` and your problem will also be resolved.

The `&#` notation is a numeric entity, giving appropriate unicode value for the character (the 'x' indicates that it's in hex).

You could always just type the character too but that requires knowledge of the ins and outs of your keyboard and region.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I don't see that they declare the entity. Should I declare it ? Where can I find that that &Ccaron is the character 'Č' or 'č'? Because I see others **(&nacute;,&lstrok;)** like &CCaron  in xml file.

Comment: I still can't it where it is defined.

Comment: Hi Kevin. The problem you have is that it isn't defined. I would make a guess that it's the upper case version because the normal convention is to make them match on case. Are there any definitions for the other entities? If so, put the declaration in there with them. If there aren't any defnitions there, you'll probably get similar issues with the other ones. Does the XML file have a DTD statement at the top?

Comment: > sorry about late reply. No there is no DTD statement in XML but an external DTD is there. But I don't see that they declare entity in DTD. What should I do ?

Comment: And I'm late again too! Sorry. If the entities are used but not declared you would need to repeat the process I described for each element. You can obtain entity lists with all the definitions you might ever want in them. You could then include those into your XML via the internal subset. If you want to know how, comment and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I found it. It is an **external .ent**. Can I point to that external .ent file from my xml while I read it because they may change it anytime.
How to include those into your XML via the internal subset?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`&Ccaron;` isn't XML it's not even defined in the HTML 4 entity reference. Which btw isn't XML. XML doesn't support all those entities, in fact, it supports very few of them but if you look up the entity and find it, you'll be able to use it's Unicode equivalent, which you can use. e.g. `&Scaron;` is invalid XML but `&#352;` isn't. (`Scaron` was the closest I could find to `Ccaron`).

Comment: Ccaron is `&#x010C;` btw. If that wasn't defined, I'd have explained combining characters I guess.

Comment: how should it be defined? what's &#x010C ?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Your XML file isn't well-formed and, so, can't be used as XmlDocument. Period.

You have two options:

- Open that file as a regular text file and fixed that symptom.
- Fix your XML generator, and that's your real problem. That generator isn't generating that file using `System.Xml`, but probably concatening several strings, as "XML is just a text file". You should repair it, or opening a generated XML file will be always a surprise.

**EDIT**: As you can't fix your XML generator, I recommend to open it with `File.ReadAllText` and execute an regular expression to re-encode that `&` or to strip off entire entity (as we can't translate it)

```
Console.WriteLine(
    Regex.Replace("<H0742>&Ccaron;opova 14, &#123; POB & SI-1000 &amp;</H0742>",
    @"&((?!#)\S*?;)?", match =>
    {
        switch (match.Value)
        {
            case "&lt;":
            case "&gt;":
            case "&amp;":
            case "&quot;":
            case "&apos;":
                return match.Value; // correctly encoded

            case "&":
                return "&amp;";

            default: // here you can choose:
                // to remove entire entity:
                return "";
                // or just encode that & character
                return "&amp;" + match.Value.Substring(1);
        }
    }));
```

Comment: I can't since I have to get the XML from a foreign country.
They will generate XML for me.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

`&Ccaron;` is an entity reference. It is likely that the entity reference is intended to be for the character **Č**, in order to produce: `Čopova`.

However, [that entity must be declared](http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/entity_declaration.shtml), or the XML parser will not know what should be substituted for the entity reference as it parses the XML.

Answer (score 0):

solution :-

```
 byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
    // Put the byte array into a stream and rewind it to the beginning 
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encodedString);
         ms.Flush();    
     ms.Position = 0;     
     // Build the XmlDocument from the MemorySteam of UTF-8 encoded bytes 
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
     xmlDoc.Load(ms);
```

Comment: you need to read your text file and then use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml); concept is that you need to encode your string .

Comment: ***byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);                                                        
                                                                     
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encodedString);                                              
            ms.Flush();                                                       
            ms.Position = 0;***

I tried like this but same error.

Comment: As this solution doesn't remove that strange character, you'll still have your parse problem.